# How do I upload new data-base structure into mysql from my development db?

Tags: mysql

we've been making changes in the MySQL database, adding tables, columns and so forth and I have a development/staging site and production. All are MySQL, staging and production hosted remote.

How do I export the table structure and bring it into the production environment?

I have been using phpMyAdmin to administer it to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On local dev system:

```
$ mysqldump -u username -p databasename > export.sql
```

On remote system:

```
$ mysql -u username -p databasename

mysql> source pathto/export.sql
```

Comment: Would I do an import?  Would that take both the data and the structure?  What if I just want structure?

Comment: To export only structure, use the following command :

$ mysqldump -u username -p databasename --no-data > export.sql

Answer (score 0):

Check out mysqldump, a command line tool that comes with MySQL, here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Using it, you can take a snapshot of both the structure and the data of your database and import it elsewhere.

Comment: I would be able to use that on a remotely hosted mysql (Joyent)?